# How to pass the data from from a lightning-datatable to a column

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-datatable, data, column

I have the following data as an array:

```
this.finalSObjectDataListChild = sObjectRelatedFieldListValues;
         console.log(this.finalSObjectDataListChild);
```

[image]

From an icon-button on the row I trigger an onrowaction: handleRowAction(event)
The array gets updated with the selected data, but my array stays empty. What am I missing? My debug shows the following:

```
    handleRowAction(event) {
        const dataRow = event.detail.row;
        this.finalSObjectDataListChild = dataRow;
        window.console.log('this.finalSObjectDataListChild: ' + this.finalSObjectDataListChild);
        window.console.log('this.finalSObjectDataListChild: ' + this.finalSObjectDataListChild.Name);
        this.modalContainer=true;
   }
```

[image]

I only see the column labels in my modal see:

[image]

Why dont I get the values in the columns? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
this.finalSObjectDataListChild = [dataRow];

This gives me te following:
[image]

I would like to achieve the following:
[{Name: 'Basic, 12 months, 1 sector', My_Duration__c: '12 months', OwnerId: '0000p000009G8FxAAA', Id: '0000p000009G8FxAAA', Owner.Name: 'John Do', …}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.detail.row` isn't an Array, it's a single object. You may have meant:

```
this.finalSObjectDataListChild = [dataRow];
```

Which would make it suitable for `lightning-datatable`.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. [dataRow only gives me the first value of the row. How do I pas the complete selected row as for example [{
    "Name": "Basic, 12 months, 1 sector",
    "My_Duration__c": "12 months",
    "Owner.Name": "John Do",
...}]

Comment: @Thomas your field mapping may be incorrect. The route property is definitely the entire row data.

Comment: Is there a way to get the index of the array? I tried so many examples but no avail.

Comment: @Thomas `const rowIndex = this.tableData.findIndex(row => row.Id === event.detail.row.Id)` is one such example, given that `this.tableData` is the source data you're working from.

Comment: Any reasons why the rowIndex always retuns -1 if not row 0?